# How to unpivot columns with same name?

Tags: python, pandas

Consider a dataframe,

```
    A   A   B   B
```

`0   1   4   7   10`
`1   2   5   8   11`
`2   3   6   9   12`

I want to append all columns with the same name.
For e.g:

```
   A    B
```

`0  1    7`
`1  2    8`
`2  3    9`
`0  4    10`
`1  5    11`
`2  6    12`

Comment: not clear...post your code

Answer (score 0):

You can create `MultiIndex` in columns and then reshape by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
s = df.columns.to_series()
df.columns = [df.columns, s.groupby(s).cumcount()]
print (df)
   A     B    
   0  1  0   1
0  1  4  7  10
1  2  5  8  11
2  3  6  9  12

df = df.stack().sort_index(level=1).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
   A   B
0  1   7
1  2   8
2  3   9
3  4  10
4  5  11
5  6  12
```

Comment: Thanks. What if the column data type is not integer?

Answer (score 0):

You could

```
In [319]: pd.concat(x for _, x in df.groupby(df.columns.duplicated(), axis=1))
Out[319]:
   A   B
0  1   7
1  2   8
2  3   9
0  4  10
1  5  11
2  6  12
```

Comment: I get `ValueError: Plan shapes are not aligned` for 3 same columns names :(